# How do I convert a string array to a byte array using Array ConvertAll?

Tags: c#, string, linq, byte, convertall

I can convert `string[]` to `byte[]` like in the following code:

```
 byte[] k = {255, 150, 155, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 55, 55, 15, 55, 155, 55};
 string st = BitConverter.ToString(Array.ConvertAll(k, Convert.ToByte));     
 byte[] kk = new byte[16];
 string[] sts = st.Split('-');            
 for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
 {
    kk[i] = Convert.ToByte(sts[i], 16);
 }
```

But I can't do the same with [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) like in the code below:

```
Array.ConvertAll(sts,item=>(byte) Convert.ToByte(item, 16))
```

How do I make this work in LINQ?

Why is it not working in the "Immediate Window" of Visual Studio?

Lambda expressions do not work in "Immediate" and "Watch" windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work. Maybe you forgot a semicolon:

```
 var a = Array.ConvertAll(sts, s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16));
```

Comment: Thanks.. that worked. But why it throws error in the Immediate window (during debug)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't catch up any exception or error.

Comment: When I try the same code (while debugging) in the "Immediate Window" of Visual Studio 2015 System.NotSupportedException error is thrown.

Comment: Have you got description: Expression cannot contain lambda expressions? Window - Watch has the same "problem".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the elegant solution to convert from a byte array (or double array) to a string and from string to byte/double array. :)

```
double[] k = {255, 150, 155, 25, 2, 55, 66};
string st = BitConverter.ToString( Array.ConvertAll(k, Convert.ToByte));
```

And from string to double array...

```
double[] kk = Array.ConvertAll(st.Split('-'), s => (double) Convert.ToByte(s, 16));
```